# grouping results in <option> in to one option if a record column is the same

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi i have a SQL query that returns results that then need to go in to a drop down in a form, however the results can look like this

```
  Number    Machine     Description             
09/14/0075  ZW01010   Back Left Armrest F55
09/14/0075  ZW01010   Back Right Armrest
09/14/0075  ZW01010   Front Left Hand Armrest F55
09/14/0075  ZW01010   Front Right Armrest F55
10/14/0060  ZW01010   Left Hand Armrest Substrate 
10/14/0060  ZW01010   Right Hand Armrest Substrate
```

at the moment i have this but of code for creating the drowndown  box

```
        <select name="WoNo">
         <?php
          foreach (PersonData::WoName(session::get('Machine')) as $a) {
             echo '<option value=' . $a["SecondRef"] . '>' . $a["Description"] . ' </option>';
         }
        ?>
        </select>
```

At the moment this puts each record in there as an option but the only value i care about in regards to the form  is the number column however i do need each of the descriptions there, so how can i adapt my code to group the that have the same value in the number column,

Here is an example how it would look with the table example i gave

```
  Option 1: Back Left Armrest F55, Back Right Armrest, Front Left Hand Armrest F55, Front Right Armrest F55
  Option 2: Left Hand Armrest Substrate, Right Hand Armrest Substrate
```

or if it is possible a better format would be

```
Option 1: Back Left Armrest F55
          Back Right Armrest
          Front Left Hand Armrest F55
          Front Right Armrest F55

Option 2:Left Hand Armrest Substrate 
         Right Hand Armrest Substrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use group  your data by number field after that you will get comma seprated values then  You can use optgoup

```
<optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT() function when retrieve data from your database instead of group it in PHP.

SELECT Number, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Description SEPARATOR ','),Machine FROM table GROUP BY Number;